# C# selecting data from a SQL database

Tags: c#, sql

Having problems selecting data from my database, any clue as to what is wrong as I've been staring at this for for a solid 2 hours.... (have made a login system to which can write and use data but can't search for it)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post the C# including the entire SQL string. We can't even see the code behind the error in your image to help you here.

Comment: `Table` is a reserved word and so needs escaping, if `name of item` is a column name it likewise needs escaping due to the spaces:  `select * from [TABLE] where [name of item] = 'xxx'` - You also must use a parameterize statement as currently you have an SQL Injection vulnerability.  You should also be using `using () {}` constructs to ensure disposal.

Comment: You should follow best practices and don't name your table `Table`. Also use parameters for your values, see [Best Practices - Executing Sql Statements](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/3589/ado-net/14261/best-practices-executing-sql-statements).

Comment: A simple rule of development is to not name anything that gives 'intellisensed' colors- it most likely is a reserved word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things to consider here:

- **DO NOT** paste screenshots, copy/paste your code. It will be easier to read, easier to copy and to index for other SO users.
- **DO NOT** concatenate strings as SQL commands, use parameters

You have syntax error, your WHERE shoud be like `WHERE Item = '" + textbox.Text + "'";`

Correct way to query database is to make parameterized query, like this:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = search;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE Item = @item";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@item", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtLogin.Text;

sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
```

`[Table]` and `Item` should be real table name and column names from table you're trying to select data from.
I'm guessing that in your case select should be something like `SELECT * FROM [Users] where Username = ...`

Comment: @Igor, thanks. I notices lack of single quotes but forgot `Table` issue. :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with SQL Query you are trying to execute.

Make sure if you are passing correct table name:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ...
```

**Table** is a keyword in SQL Server so it cannot be use like this in query.

Event if you have a table in db with name 'Table' then use following query

```
    SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`Table` is a keyword on SQL you cant use it as is. If indeed you have named one of your tables as table, which I highly recommended not to, you must use brackets:

```
Select * from [Table]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with SQL Query you are trying to execute.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE "condition";
```

use that query.